# Javascript scrolling, XHTML Doctype, IE6 - IE8 and a coronary

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, doctype

I've been working for hours on this and I can't figure it out.

I've got a setup that pulls some coordinate data into javascript and parses it into an interactive map (using canvas {and excanvas for IE6 users}) on the browser for the user. Everything is working fine except for one problem: when hovering on the map after scrolling down the page, the hover is off by the amount scrolled.

This is the code as-is:

```
function getOffset(evt) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    setPageTopLeft(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));
    return [(evt.clientX - obj.pageLeft), (evt.clientY - obj.pageTop)];
}

function setPageTopLeft(o) {
    var top = 0, left = 0, obj = o;

    alert('scrollTop w/ getElementById: ' + document.getElementById("myCanvas").scrollTop + ' scrollTop w/ .body.:' + document.body.scrollTop + ' window.pageYOffset: ' + window.pageYOffset);

    top = document.getElementById("myCanvas").scrollTop;
    left = document.getElementById("myCanvas").scrollLeft;

    while (o.offsetParent) {
        left += o.offsetLeft;
        top += o.offsetTop;
        o = o.offsetParent;
    };
    obj.pageTop = top;
    obj.pageLeft = left;
}
```

Using doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

The alert() is the tests I've run trying to get it to work. I know that firefox works with window.pageYOffset, but I need something that works with IE6 + IE7 + IE8.

Comment: Do you mean "corollary"?

Comment: Sorry i was trying to be funny :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I was being a moron. It's fairly well documented to use 'document.documentElement.scrollTop', which I thought meant I should replace 'documentElement' with the element I was currently using. You should actually literally be using document.documentElement.scrollTop to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's a year after the original post, so hope this is a useful addendum.

It may be "well documented" to use scrollTop, but I found that while IE8 doesn't have a value for window.pageYOffset which I was using, it works in Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome...

and the 'well documented' fix does NOT work in Chrome or Safari... at this time.

Comment: I adapated the original code to be used with jQuery since it normalizes all these accessors - much easier!